# Is it possible to authenticate with a Service Principle to Azure DevOps Analytics Views?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-devops-analytics

I am having difficulties accessing DevOps Analytics view trough ADF. I am currently able to fetch data using an OData linked service and using a personal access token (PAT) but this is not an option for me as it is tied to a user. Is it possible to do this trough a Service Principle?

Comment: I am also looking to authenticate Azure DevOps using PAT token from ADF. Could you please help me with Which authentication type you have used in oData linked service and how you are passing the value of PAT token?

Comment: @KuldeepSingh https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page here instructions and then in ADF create an OData linked service.
Service URL: http://analytics.dev.azure/organization_name/project_name/_odata/v2.0
Authentication: Anonymous
Headers:
Authorization : Bearer [base64_encoded_PAT]